# Can you have multiple bootstrap versions on the same page?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I'd like embed bootstrap on a page that has an old version of bootstrap (version 3 and version 4 of bootstrap, however, there are js conflicts.

I'm embedding it in a 3rd party site I have no control over.

Is there a bootstrap noConflicts mode like jQuery (https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Comment: I would imagine you will have CSS conflicts too depending on the specificity of some classes/id's. Why do you need to have two versions of the same library ? I would choose one or the other

Comment: why? per question I'm embedding it in a 3rd party site I have no control over.

Answer (score 1):

bootstrap does have noConflict - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/

less can be used to namespace the css,  however, I needed to manually namespace the classes/id in bootstraps js... :(